# MySQL database connected to a droplist

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code keep showing this:

[image]

instead of showing the database records.

```
<tr><td>Wie is jou favoriete popgroep? </td>
<td><select>
<?php
$sql="SELECT band,bandid FROM bands order by band"; 


foreach ($result->query($sql) as $row){

echo "<option value=$row[bandID]>$row[band]</option>"; 

}
?>
</select>
</td></tr>
```

My database:

[image]

Why does it keep saying `$row[band]` and not the records in my database?

Comment: Post your complete code!!

Comment: can you please show us the code?

Comment: Is this a php file or perhaps an html file? And are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: its html file, does it need to be a php file?

Comment: Yup. You can instruct your webserver to process .html files as php, but the default (and most common) way is to use `.php` file extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with wrong placement of variable in a string definition.

This does not work: `echo "<option value=$row[bandID]>$row[band]</option>";`... Instead use one of these:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['bandID'] . "\">\"" . $row['band'] . "\"</option>";
```

Or this alternative notation:

```
echo "<option value=\"{$row['bandID']}\">\"{$row['band']}\"</option>";
```

If things get more complex this might also come in handy:

```
echo sprintf(
    '<option value="%s">"%s"</option>', 
    $row['bandID'], 
    $row['band']
);
```

And in case you are nmot 100% certain about the contents of that array you also need to escape values when inserting them into html markup:

```
echo sprintf(
    '<option value="%s">"%s"</option>', 
    htmlspecialchars($row['bandID']), 
    htmlspecialchars($row['band'])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['bandID'].'">'.$row['band'].'</option>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use quotes inside foreach, Also replace `$conn` with your variable

**Edited**

```
<tr><td>Wie is jou favoriete popgroep? </td>
<td><select>
<?php
$sql="SELECT Band,BandID FROM bands order by band"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "<option value=".$row['BandID'].">".$row['Band']."</option>";
    }
}

?>
</select>
</td></tr>
```